# How can i change the size of touchpad?

Tags: javascript

```
//x and y is absolute coordinate of the touchpad
//dx and dy is the change in mouse position since the last acquisition
// the variables screenX and screenY are the new positions x and y on the screen
var maxScreenX =800;  // width Screen
var maxScreenY =300;  // height Screen


function transfer1(x,y,dx,dy)
{


}
```

The size of the touchpad is 200x200 but I want to draw on the size which the screen has so 800x300 so that I can draw from one end to another end.
How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "touchpad"? For me, a touchpad is the mouse replacement used in a notebook computer, changing it's size requires a saw or maybe a sharp knive and inevitable ends with a broken computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if i understand the issue correctly, but i assume you just want to translate x and y coordinates from 200x200 to 800x300.

```
function transfer1(x,y,dx,dy)
{
  dx += x*maxScreenX/200
  dy += y*maxScreenY/200
}
```

This assumes center of the frame is `[x=0, y=0]` so values can be negative, if thats not the case you will need some `if` statement to handle decrementation